# How to remove first 3 lines of multiple .md files with Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

I need to remove first three lines of multiple markdown files structured like that:

```
|- Folder
  | - 01-07-22.md
  | - 02-07-22.md
  | - 03-07-22.md
  | - ...
```

I would like to do this with Mac Terminal (if possible) because I have no expertise with any coding language and thus I don't have any coding platform installed on my computer.

Also I would like to know if other than deleting first 3 lines is possible to add "##" at the very beginning of every document.

#### What works:

- This work:

  ```
  sed -i '' '1,3d' Folder/*.md
  ```
- The following command works also:

  ```
  sed -i '' '1i\
  ##' *.md
  ```

  But it does not add a new line before the first line.
- This does not work at all:

  ```
  sed -i '' '1s
  /^/##/' *.md
  ```

How to add an empty line at the beginning and "##" at the beginning of the now second line? Explaination:
From this:

```
# First line of example .md file
Second line of example .md
...
```

To this:

```
### First line of example .md file
Second line of example .md
...
```

Comment: Wait, you want to add an **empty** line, but prepend "##" to an existing line? That was not clear from your question (at least how I have read it). That's why Stackoverflow almost requires to include [mre]s in the question: show an example file (just the first few lines) and the expected output. Use code block formatting to prevent any formatting issues.

Comment: @knittl sorry, now I've added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use (GNU) `sed`. I hope that the Mac version supports all the required flags and features.

To delete the first 3 lines:

```
sed -i '1,3d' Folder/*.md
```

To prepend the line `##` to every file:

```
sed -i '1i##' Folder/*.md
```

To prefix the existing first line with `##`:

```
sed -i '1s/^/##/' Folder/*.md
```

The original files are overwritten without confirmation, but you can specify `-i.bak` to create backup files, e.g. `Folder/01-07-22.md.bak`. Specify `-i ''` to disable backup file creation.

Certain `sed` implementations might always require an argument after `-i`, so go with `-i.bak` or `-i .bak`.

If prepending a line does not work, try a different syntax (the newline is important):

```
sed -i .bak '1i\
##' Folder/*.md
```

If that doesn't work either, there's another form how sed could be invoked:

```
sed -i .bak -e '1i\' -e '##' Folder/*.md
```

---

If you want to modify the first line *and* add an empty line before it, e.g. transforming

```
1
2
3
```

into

```
##1
2
3
```

would require you to use the following command:

```
sed -i .bak '1s/^/##/;1i\

' Folder/*.md
```

Comment: You don't need GNU `sed` for this. However, the Mac (BSD) `sed` requires an argument after `-i`; so, `sed -i '' '1,3d' Folder/*.md` etc if you don't want `-i .bak`

Comment: Also the `i` command has poor portability; not at my computer, but try following `i` with a backslash and a newline before the string you want to insert.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, extended and adapted my answer.

Comment: What's the difference between sed `-i '1s/^/##/' Folder/*.md` and `sed -i '1i##' Folder/*.md` ?

Comment: Anyway, the solution proposed by @tripleee works on my computer, but the ones proposed originally don't and terminal tells me "invalid command code". I've managed to remove first three lines, now how to add ## in the first line before the first character?

Comment: Edit: managed to do it by using `sed -i '' '1i\
##' Folder/*.md`

Comment: @Edoardo the `1s` variant prepends _to_ the first line, the `1i` variant adds an extra line before the first one.

Comment: @knittl I've used `sed -i '' '1s /^/##/' *.md`, it works by putting "##" at the first line, but I want an empty line at the beginning at it does not add it, nor with `sed -i '' '1i\
##' *.md` an empty line at the beginning gets added. It says: " newline can not be used as a string delimiter"

Comment: @Edoardo newlines get removed in comments. Can you edit your question to include the exact command which you have executed, including any newlines?

Comment: @knittl Added please check, thank's

Comment: @knittl I've also tried `sed -i .bak -e '1i\' -e '##' Folder/*.md` with no success

Comment: @knittl Hi, I've tried your last command but it does not work, it just add "##" on the first line, also how to remove .bak file creation? I don't need it

Comment: Again, just use `-i ''` if you don't want a backup.